# Hyper-V: Exclude Hypervisor from VM network

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I need to run virtual machines on a Windows Server Hypervisor in a different IP network than the hypervisor itself. It is mandatory that the VMs cannot communicate with their hypervisor, but they still need to communicate with other machines in that IP network who are not VMs on that virtual switch. (To my understanding this prevents me from using the "internal" and "private" virtual-switch types, right?)

I have my management network: 192.168.178.0/24
The VMs are supposed to run in: 192.168.100.0/24

Even though I wouldn't feel comfortable with such a solution anyway, I would guess using an external virtual switch and deactivating it in the HV-OS would also prevent the VMs from communicating outside the virtual area.

What would be the correct solution to this? Dedicating an extra hardware NIC would not be a problem if necessary.

Comment: What about using an External Switch in Hyper-V (I do this). This is equivalent to a VMware / VBOX Bridged NIC.  You can also set up a new Internal switch and give that the .100 subnet. This is equivalent to NAT.

Comment: Wouldn't this allow the VMs to communicate with the Hypervisor? This must not be possible.

Comment: Any External / Internal connection will be required to do what you want but (of necessity in design) will allow communication with the Host.

Comment: You need to use the external switch, if you uncheck "llow management operating system to share this network adapter" this will keep the host off that NIC. Now, you if you are plugging this NIC and host PC nic into the same switch and all your other systems are on the same physical network, you'll need to manage the hyper-v host the same way as any of the other systems on the 192.168.100.x network.  If you're separating these systems purely by IP/subnet then the host and other .100 PCs will all have the same access or lack of access.